# Paypal Adaptive Delayed Chained Payment in Paypal- Partial Refund

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

We are using Adaptive Delayed Chained Payment method to transfer funds from one party to another party with ourselves as an intermediary merchant that takes a percentage. In this scenario we are the primary receiver and there is a secondary receiver as well. In case of a partial refund to the party sending the money (the client) we need to transfer the balance fee less our commission to the secondary receiver.

It seems that we cannot call the "Execute" function after the partial refund process to complete the transaction flow. i.e. once the the client is partially refunded, we as the intermediary and primary receiver hold the balance funds. The secondary receiver does not get paid since we cannot call the "Execute" function. So the balance fee is stuck at the primary receiver end. So how can we send the balance fee to the secondary receiver in this partial refunding process? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Two of us have searched this site and other sites, but cannot find anywhere that addresses this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could just create a fresh Pay request with a single receiver on it to sends whatever funds you owe to whomever you owe it.